# MySQL InnoDB data restore using 3 files

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

I am able to restore `MySQL` table data along with structure with indexes (InnoDB Engine) using 3 files. `MyTable.frm`, `MyTable.ibd` and `ibdata1`.

Can any body confirm, will these 3 files suffice to restore data for all scenarios. Else, is there any other files that needs to be considered while restoring data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, two files will suffice:

- `MyTable.frm`
- `MyTable.ibd`

The table schema you'll get from the frm file and the data - from ibd file.

or

- `MyTable.ibd`
- `ibdata1`.

`ibdata1` stores InnoDB dictionary which describes the schema, too.

Sometimes, a trained eye can guess the schema from ibd file, but it must be relatively simple.

Comment: No.  All three files are actually needed.  5.7 relaxes the requirement, but adds the need to export/import "transportable tablespaces".  (I have to down vote it because it is misinformation.)

Comment: Rick James, I'm sorry, but you are wrong.

Comment: idbdata1 has a "tablespace number" that must match the .ibd.  I think that is the reason for not moving them separately.  The .frm will be obviated some time in 5.7.  Do you have a reference that affirms your contention?

Comment: check my blog, I wrote tons on the matter.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html -- Portability Considerations for .ibd Files

When you move or copy .ibd files, the database directory name must be the same on the source and destination systems. The table definition stored in the InnoDB shared tablespace includes the database name. The transaction IDs and log sequence numbers stored in the tablespace files also differ between databases.  (etc)

Comment: Link to your blog?

Comment: https://twindb.com/ . Will you come to the next Percona Live? Bring either couple of files and bottle of whisky and I will restore you the table ;-)

Comment: I'm talking on `PARTITIONing` in Amsterdam next month.

Comment: You win (sort of):  https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/  I say "sort of" because it seems to require compiling your special C program to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

All three files are necessary and sufficient for restoring *all* the InnoDB tables.

You *cannot* load a single InnoDB table with a technique like that.  (MyISAM is a different story.)

5.6.8 has "transportable tablespaces" which lets you move a single non-partitioned table from one place to another, but it takes special instructions, not just file copies.

> ----- 2012-08-07 5.6.6 Milestone 9 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB -----
>
> InnoDB tables now support the notion of “transportable tablespaces”,
>   allowing .ibd files to be exported from a running MySQL instance and
>   imported into another running instance. The FOR EXPORT clause of the
>   FLUSH TABLE ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html )
>   command writes any unsaved changes from InnoDB memory buffers to the
>   .ibd file. After copying the .ibd file and a separate metadata file to
>   the other server, you can use the DISCARD TABLESPACE and IMPORT
>   TABLESPACE clauses of the ALTER TABLE (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html ) statement to
>   bring the table data into a different MySQL instance.
>
> For more information, see Copying Tablespaces to Another Server
>   (Transportable Tablespaces) (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html ).